# What is the capability of PWA for Windows?

Tags: windows, desktop-application, progressive-web-apps

I'm totally new to PWA (rather I'm still considering adopting PWA or go Electron).

Looking at the concept and guides of the app on the web, it seems that the capability of it is to this extent, thus;

1. Access web APIs securely and easily
   Yes, as it is the alternative implementation of web apps.
2. Access local storage of the PC for the app
   Yes, through HTML5 web storage.
3. Access any local files in the PC
   No?
4. Communicate with another desktop app through TCP connection
   Yes? By posting/getting some query to localhost for example?
5. Obtain system info like PC status or installation path of another desktop app
   No?

How many of my understandings are correct? Is there another capability or limitation to be specially noted?

Comment: You cannot obtain Geolocation in the Background so no Geofences Location alerts etc. W3C and IETF flatly refuse to standardize this functionality even though the Service Worker hooks are ready and willing to go: - https://github.com/RichardMaher/Brotkrumen see also https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/issues/745

Comment: Interesting, thanks!